# Why do my own edits show up in the suggested edit icon?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

So I made a tag wiki edit today, and was surprised to see the little orange box in the Stack Exchange bar appear with a pretty "2" in it.

[image]

Upon clicking the box I am told there are no pending edits.

[image]

It would be nice if the icon didn't appear when it's just my own edits awaiting.

<sup>I'm sure someone has addressed this before, but I couldn't find it, probably because I'm not sure what to call that orange box/icon</sup>

Comment: @ShadowWizard I bit old, but I guess that isn't going to change.

Comment: Yep, as Nick said fixing this bug cost too much, and not money. :)